# JS function not updating an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I've simplified a function I've been working on, but still console.log equals 0 when the function is run. What am I doing wrong that would be  causing the object not to update?

```
var x = { y: 0 };

var z = 5;

function addStrokesToScore(a, b) {
 a += b;
}

addStrokesToScore(x.y, z);

console.log(x.y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addStrokesToScore(x.y, z)` passes the **values** of `x.y` and `z` into the function, it doesn't pass a reference to the property/variable. You can't change the property/variable within the function; there's no link back to it.

The normal thing here is to *return* the new value:

```
function addStrokesToScore(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

x.y = addStrokesToScore(x.y, z);
```

Alternately, you can pass in a reference to the `x` object, and use that reference to update its `y` property:

```
function addStrokesToScore(obj, b) {
  obj.y += b;
}

addStrokesToScore(x, z);
```

But in general, barring a good reason, you'd want to use the `return` option instead.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are passing the value not the object reference:

```js
var x = {
  y: 0
};

var z = 5;

function addStrokesToScore(o, b) { //note
  o.y += b; //note
}

addStrokesToScore(x, z); //note

alert(x.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a number, which is immutable. You need to pass a reference to the entire object:

```
var x = { y: 0 };

var z = 5;

function addStrokesToScore(a, b) {
 a.y += b;
}

addStrokesToScore(x, z);

console.log(x.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

No place you are updating the x.y, you are just passing it to the fn and updating inside a fn local variable 'a'.

You can either add `x.y+=b;`

or add return a to the function and make your call statement as `x.y=addStrokesToScore(x.y, z);`

Answer (score 1):

by passing x.y you are passing the value 0 and not the reference. Use this-

```
var x = { y: 0 };

var z = 5;

function addStrokesToScore(a, b) {
     a.y += b;
}

addStrokesToScore(x, z);

console.log(x.y);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pgwkuaq5/